# Create a Function with Generic Type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using this syntax at various places,

```
CASE WHEN [dbo].[IsNullOrWhiteSpace](@MyColumn) = 1 OR [dbo].[IsNullOrWhiteSpace](Name) = 0 THEN [Name] ELSE @MyColumn END
```

The only change is Name and @MyColumn. But MyColumn can be any type. Any way to create a function that do this stuff but with genric type. This is what I am looking,

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetParameterOrPreviousValue]
(
    @Value1 AnyType
    ,@Value2 AnyType
)
RETURNS AnyType
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN CASE WHEN [dbo].[IsNullOrWhiteSpace](@Value1) = 1 OR [dbo].[IsNullOrWhiteSpace](@Value2) = 0 THEN @Value2 ELSE @Value1 END;

END
```

See the AnyType.

**Update**

Here is my IsNullOrEmpty,

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[IsNullOrWhiteSpace]
                (
                    @Value nvarchar(MAX)
                )
                RETURNS bit
                AS
                BEGIN

                    RETURN CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(@Value,''))) = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;

                END
```

and I am using this in a UPDATE statement,

```
UPDATE T SET    [Name] = dbo.GetParameterOrPreviousValue(@Name, Name) 
                ,[Gender] = dbo.GetParameterOrPreviousValue(@Gender, Gender)
        ,[Location] = dbo.GetParameterOrPreviousValue(@Location, Location)
        ,[RawData] = dbo.GetParameterOrPreviousValue(@RawData, RawData)
```

Comment: is GetParameterOrPreviousValue a function here ?

Comment: you have declaires name  stored with a function GetParameterOrPreviousValue ?

Comment: @CodeLover, GetParameterOrPreviousValue and GetOneValue are same

Comment: i asked you declaires [name] = dbo.getparameterorpreviousvalue ...i asked you declaired getparameterorpreviousvalue is declaired as a function here ?

Comment: i asked is getparameterorpreviousvalue you declaired here is function or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can use [sql_variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). Also what about `[dbo].[IsNullOrWhiteSpace]`? Does it takes a `String` type?

Comment: Actually IsNullOrWhiteSpace accept nvarchar. It is showing me conversion error? Should I make IsNullOrWhiteSpace as sql_variant? But , I am using this function in UPDATE STATEMENT. `SET [Name] = dbo.GetParameterOrPreviousValue(@Name, Name)`

Comment: @user960567: In this case sql_variant value will be implicitly converted to varchar on `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` call.

Comment: Means it is not possible because I have NVARCHAR(MAX) which is not supported by sql_variant. There is no similar concept in SQL SERVER that is akin to C# Generric T

Comment: @user960567 Also you can place `LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(@Value,'')))` into the `GetOneValue` function to avoid `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` function call.

Comment: But then the UPDATE will break :(

Comment: @user960567 - try writing a generic method in C# that uses `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` and doesn't similarly have to cheat and actually explicitly convert to a string.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I understand what r u saying. But there should be support of Genric Types in SQL SERVER. At least in CLR SP

Answer (score 2):

There's the "old-skool" [`sql_variant`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx) type:

> A data type that stores values of various SQL Server-supported data types.

But notice that most of the modern data types (e.g. `varchar(max)`, `geography`, etc) aren't supported.

---

If all you want to do is ignore null parameter values, you can use [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):

```
COALESCE(@Name,Name)
```

If you want to ignore null and *empty* parameter values, you can use `COALESCE` and [`NULLIF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx):

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(@Name,''),Name)
```

I'd resist the urge to treat all manner of whitespace the same as `NULL`s, generally.

Comment: See the above comment?

Comment: @user960567 - I've added some other options that you may not have been aware of. Also, try to avoid using positional language (above, below) when referring to questions and comments on SO because voting and randomization can affect the order in which these are displayed.

Comment: I am aware of. Actually, if you see above, I am using this in my Update statement. The point is that I just want to use `SET [Name] = dbo.GetParameterOrPreviousValue(@Name, Name)` Name can be any type including nvarchar. Is it possible?

Comment: @user960567 - since it's only *meaningful* to talk about whitespace for `varchar` types, for most other datatypes, using `COALESCE(@Parameter,Column)` is more idiomatic and understandable to most people. That should reduce you to only needing the function for string types - if you still think a function adds value - or alternatively just use `COALESCE(NULLIF(RTRIM(@Parameter),''),Column)` - again, if you really think that treating all empty strings as `NULL`s is actually a sensible thing.